# SKProductsRequestDelegate failure

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

The SKProductsRequestDelegate has one single method:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

Usually, I find these sorts of delegates will have several methods for handling multiple cases, rather than just success. For example:

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *) error
```

How can I check if this code fails for some reason, eg. the user is offline?

```
SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] ... ];
productsRequest.delegate = self;
[productsRequest start];
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`SKProductsRequestDelegate` conforms to the `SKRequestDelegate` protocol.

There you find

```
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request
```