# Help...didReceiveResponse is not called

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Grettings to you everybody!

Here me still finding problem with implementing storekit framework.
When i run the code on my device, it sends the request but the didReceiveResponse is not getting called.am i doing wrong in my code?
Please guide me up...Thanks for any help

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   NSLog(@"View is loaded");

   [self requestProductData];

   if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
   {
      NSLog(@"can make payments");

   }
   else
   {
      NSLog(@"cannot make payments");
   }

   [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void) requestProductData
{
   NSSet *productIDs = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"com.mycompany.inapppurchasetesting.productid", nil];

   SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIDs];

   request.delegate = self;

   NSLog(@"Requesting");

   [request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;

    NSArray *myInvalidProducts = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

   NSLog(@"Did recieve response");

   NSLog(@"Response count is %d",response.products.count);

   NSLog(@"Invalid response count is %d",response.invalidProductIdentifiers.count);

   for (int i = 0; i<myProduct.count; i++)
   {
        NSLog(@"t:%@",[[myProduct objectAtIndex:i] localizedTitle]);
   }

    for(int i = 0; i < myInvalidProducts.count; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid products:%@",[myInvalidProducts objectAtIndex:i]);
    }

    // populate UI
    [request autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some memory management bugs in this code, but I don't see a problem with it that would prevent the delegate from being called.

If I recall correctly, StoreKit may not fully work on the simulator. Have you tried this on the device?

Also, per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474384/skproductsrequestdelegate-failure), you can add a callback for errors to help diagnose your issue, like so:

```
- (void) request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *errorMessage = [error localizedDescription]; 
    [self notifyUserInterfaceOfError:errorMessage];
}
```